# How to query through a Foreign key field inside django inline forms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have these models:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    company         = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    party_ac        = models.ForeignKey(Ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='partyledger')
    purchase        = models.ForeignKey(Ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='purchaseledger')
    total           = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)

class Stock_total(models.Model):
    company     = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    purchases   = models.ForeignKey(Purchase,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=False,related_name='purchasetotal') 
    stockitem   = models.ForeignKey(Stockdata,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True,related_name='purchasestock') 
    total     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,default=0.00,null=True,blank=True)
```

This are my forms:

```
class Purchase_form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model  = Purchase

        fields = ('Company','Party_ac', 'purchase', 'sub_total')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.User = kwargs.pop('User', None)        
        self.Company = kwargs.pop('Company', None)
        super(Purchase_form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['party_ac'].queryset = Ledger1.objects.filter(Q(Company = self.Company) , Q(group1_Name__group_Name__icontains='Sundry Creditors') | Q(group1_Name__group_Name__icontains='Bank Accounts') | Q(group1_Name__group_Name__icontains='Cash-in-hand') | Q(group1_Name__Master__group_Name__icontains='Sundry Creditors') | Q(group1_Name__Master__group_Name__icontains='Bank Accounts') | Q(group1_Name__Master__group_Name__icontains='Cash-in-hand'))
        self.fields['party_ac'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'select2_demo_2 form-control',}
        self.fields['purchase'].queryset = Ledger1.objects.filter(Q(Company = self.Company) ,Q(group1_Name__group_Name__icontains='Purchase Accounts') | Q(group1_Name__Master__group_Name__icontains='Purchase Accounts'))
        self.fields['purchase'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'select2_demo_2 form-control',}
        self.fields['total'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control',}

class Stock_Totalform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model  = Stock_Total
        fields = ('stockitem', 'Total_p')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Stock_Totalform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['stockitem'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'select2_demo_2 form-control',}
        self.fields['total'].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control',}


Purchase_formSet = inlineformset_factory(Purchase, Stock_Total,
                                            form=Stock_Totalform, extra=3)
```

The views:

```
class Purchase_createview(ProductExistsRequiredMixin,Company_only_accounts_mixins,LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    form_class  = Purchase_form
    template_name = 'stockkeeping/purchase/purchase_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Purchase_createview, self).get_context_data(**kwargs) 
        company_details = get_object_or_404(Company, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        context['company_details'] = company_details
        selectdatefield_details = get_object_or_404(Selectdatefield, pk=self.kwargs['pk3'])
        context['selectdatefield_details'] = selectdatefield_details
        if self.request.POST:
            context['stocks'] = Purchase_formSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['stocks'] = Purchase_formSet()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        c = Company.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        form.instance.Company = c
        context = self.get_context_data()
        stocks = context['stocks']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()
            if stocks.is_valid():
                stocks.instance = self.object
                stocks.save()
        return super(Purchase_createview, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        data = super(Purchase_createview, self).get_form_kwargs()
        data.update(
            Company=Company.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
            )
        return data
```

I want to perform a queryset method for `stockitem` field in `Stock_Totalform` which I will make specific to `Company` like I have done for `Party_ac` and `purchase` in  `Purchase_form` above..

When I try to do the same for `Stock_Totalform` objects it gives me no result..

I tried like above doing: `self.Company = kwargs.pop('Company', None)` using the `get_form_kwargs` function in views.

But it looks like it doesnot works for the `ForeignKey` field which is inlined with a `parent` model.

Can anyone help to to solve this issue.

Thank you

Comment: show us the code where you've tried in your view to pass the company to the formset. you probably want to pass a custom parameter to your form like described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms) (using `form_kwargs`)

Comment: Thank you @dirkgroten passing a custom parameter solves the issue.